# Using stellar-lib api with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

this is probably a silly question but am new to Meteor and struggling a bit. I want to build a [stellar](https://www.stellar.org/api/) app that tweets when you get stellar. There is a nice Javascript API [stellar-lib](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-lib) that works on node, but im unsure how to access the modules in Meteor...

Comment: to know how to use npm modules in your app visit here http://www.meteorsnippets.com/blog/using-npm-modules-in-your-project

Answer (score 0):

I'm also building an app with Meteor and stellar-lib and have found two options:

1) You can manually copy over the built `stellar-lib.js` or `stellar-lib-min.js` from the `build/` directory from either the github repo or the `node_modules` folder you installed it to when you ran the `npm install` command.

If you do this, you will have to copy the `.js` file to `client/compatibility`, otherwise stellar-lib will not work (**note**: this means you can only use Stellar on the client).

2) If you need it on the server, you can also have `browserify` wrap `stellar-lib` for you, then copy the output to `lib/` in your Meteor app's root directory. I did this in my repo [here](https://github.com/sunny-g/whuffie/tree/master/.gulp) with `gulp`.

Here's a short explanation to how 2) works:

`.gulp` is where I'll install my NPM modules where they will be ignored by the Meteor build environment (because the folder is hidden).

In `deps.js`, I require the modules I would want to use in my Meteor app as I would if I was using them in a traditional `node.js` app. `package.json` defines the modules I'll install with NPM and the `gulpfile.js` describes a `build` task that will resolve my `require` statements and output a single `deps.js` file that includes my dependencies to my Meteor app's `lib/` folder.